# What does a language parameterizing another language mean?

Tags: set-theory, formal-languages, descriptive-set-theory

I am reviewing my class notes, and I came across this expression -

The $n$-th slice of $A \subseteq \Sigma^*$ is

$A_n = \{x \in \Sigma^* \mid {\langle n,x \rangle} \in A \}$

$C$ *parameterizes* $D$ (also called $C$ is *universal* for $D$) if,

$\exists A \in C \quad\text{such that}\quad D = \{A_n \mid n\in \mathbb{N}\}$

Also, please note, $\exists$ doesn't mean there exists here. It stands for existential projection.

$\exists B=\{x\in \Sigma^* \mid \exists w\in \Sigma^*\ {\langle x,w \rangle}\in B\}$

As a follow-up, I'm also trying to understand the following statement -

$D$ is *$C$-countable* if,

$\exists A \in C \quad\text{such that}\quad D \subseteq \{A_n \mid n\in \mathbb{N}\}$

Comment: The $\exists$ in $\exists A\in C$ means "there exists," not projection.

Comment: The first step is trying to understand what an "nth slice" is. assuming that $\Sigma$ is the *alphabet* (set of symbols) and [$\Sigma^*$](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kleene_star) is the set of all strings over symbols in $\Sigma$.

Comment: Example: given set $A$ of strings, the $0$-th slice $A_0$ will be obtained considering all strings of $A$ that have $0$ as first symbol.

Comment: For "C parameterizes D", given sets $C, D$ of strings, **if** there is some subset $A$ of $C$ such that $D$ is the collection of "slices" of $A$.

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA Thank you. The last line is not particularly clear. Should D contain "all" slices of A?

Comment: @desert_ranger Not necessarily - the idea is that $A$ is allowed to "overshoot" (which gives us that subsets of $C$-countable sets are $C$-countable, which would *not* generally be true if we weren't allowed to overshoot).